# For loop with array not working for me

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Simple question here. Why is this giving an error?

```
  for ($k = 1; $k < 17; $k++){

 echo $result[0]->answer_."$k";

}
```

Edit: contents of $result:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [entry_id] => 37 [answer_1] => 20-24 yrs old [answer_2] => No [answer_3] => Yes [answer_4] => No [answer_5] => 236.7 [answer_6] => Ideal blood pressure – upper figure between 91 & 120, lower figure between 61& 80 [answer_7] => No, I haven’t had it checked [answer_8] => No, I quit more than 10 years ago [answer_9] => I sometimes get 150 minutes or more per week [answer_10] => 2-5 hours per day [answer_11] => Every day [answer_12] => Less often or never [answer_13] => Every day [answer_14] => 3-4 days a week [answer_15] => Never [answer_16] => imperial ) )

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information here to answer your question without a crystal ball. What's the current contents of `$results`? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for ($k = 1; $k < 17; $k++){

    echo $result[0]->{'answer_'.$k};

}
```

Updated based on comment from mpen below

Comment: That's different. `->` references an object property, `[]` is an array index. Impossible to know what op wants. For all we know, he has an array of objects, with a property called `answer_` and he wants to typecast `$k` to a string.

Comment: Yeah I figured maybe they have a bunch of member variables with incrementing numbers and they are trying to print them out? In JS you can do it with an object literal I just don't remember if you can with PHP. I guess not!

Comment: Nope. They're separate concepts in PHP. I think the syntax is `$result[0]->{'answer_'.$k}` in PHP.

Comment: That worked. Weird that I had to put it in curly brackets. Thanks. Just saved me having to write a big switch statement.

Comment: It's not weird. You are dynamically changing the variable name. Check here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php